# HTML POST to multiple .php files

Tags: php, html, forms, post, http-post

This is my current form.

```
## on index.php
        <form action="index2.php" method="POST">
            <select name="profile">
                <option value="basic" selected>Easy</option>
                <option value="intermediate">Medium</option>
                <option value="advanced">Hard</option>
            </select>
            <br>
                <input type="submit"/>
        </form>
```

On index2.php, I can successfully do $_POST['profile']. However, I want to $_POST['profile'] on another .php file I have and it's called test.php.

When I attempt to do $_POST['profile'] on test.php and assign it to a variable $test, an error is returned.

```
Notice: Undefined index: profile in C:\xampp\htdocs\testfolder\test.php on line 15
```

Code causing the error:

```
$test = $_POST['profile'];

## this is on test.php
```

Expected Outcome: Successfully POST "profile".

How can I do so?

Comment: if you want the value to persist, you can use sessions

Comment: Please show us the code you're you're having issues with. It's also unclear how you load the test.php file. Are you changing the action in the form, redirecting the user on index2.php or just including it in index2.php?

Comment: Question has been edited to show the cause of the error. All these files index.php, index2.php and test.php are within the same directory and I'm running them using localhost as the URL.When the submit button is pressed on index.php, user is redirected to index2.php. The main problem here is I can't do a $_POST['profile'] on test.php.

Comment: I'll require the $_POST['profile'] information on test.php in order to do some if-else statements, but since I can't retrieve it, it's abit of an issue.

Comment: How did you head into `test.php`? By url or by redirect from `index2.php`?

Comment: Redirect from index2.php.

Comment: If you redirect the client, it will make a new clean GET request to that file so all previously posted data are gone. If you want data to persist between multiple requests, you can, as @Kevin suggests in the first comment, use sessions. On index2.php, start a session, store the posted data in a session variable. Then on test.php, you start the session and read the session variable to get the value again. But if you just want to handle the post request, do that in index2.php. Why redirect to test.php?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store that variable into a session variable after POST and you can access that variable from anywhere in the code in every page.

Your form:

```
<form action="index2.php" method="POST">
    <select name="profile">
        <option value="basic" selected>Easy</option>
        <option value="intermediate">Medium</option>
        <option value="advanced">Hard</option>
    </select>
    <br>
        <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

On page index2.php youu have to capture the POST data by using this
index2.php

```
<?php 

session_start(); // starting the session

if(isset($_POST)){
      $_SESSION['profile'] = $_POST['profile'] // sets the $_POST['profile'] value to $_SESSION['profile'] 
}
?>
```

Now $_SESSION will become your globel varibale you can access it at anytime any page just have to add session_start(); on every page.

test.php:

```
<?php 
session_start(); //starting the session
echo $_SESSION['profile'];
?>
```

It will return your desire value on any page. Please read [$_SESSION](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php) here.